# Data annotations do not work with jQuery unobtrusive validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, data-annotations

Live example: http://mvc.renethomassen.dk/

I have used jQuery unobtrusive validation with data annotations (MVC 4), when I publish my website, properties with multiple annotations do not work, validate.

This works:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Skriv venligst dit navn")]
public string Navn { get; set; }
```

The following does not work (it works on localhost). Why?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Skriv venligst din emailadresse")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Angiv en gyldig emailadresse")]
public string EmailAdresse { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [DataTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute.aspx) instead of EmaillAddressAttribute

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Skriv venligst din Emailadresse")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddresss, ErrorMessage = "Angiv en gyldig email")]
public string EmailAdresse { get; set; }
```

Comment: It did´t work, but if I use html.editorfor insted of html.textboxfor it works.

Comment: @RenéThomassen Ah, yes.  You should almost always use `EditorFor` to get the MVC magics.  When you use `TextBoxFor` you are telling Razor that you know what you are doing and to back off.